# Map Json to Interface with Optional fields - Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, interface

I would like to create a common interface for following json object:

**TYPE**

```
{"transactionId: "<UUID>", "details": "<message event/action description>", "err": "<Optional, error description>", ...<additional log information>}
```

**EXAMPLE INPUTS**

```
2044-08-09T02:12:51.253Z - info - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e978","details":"Service is started"}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.255Z - info - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e821","details":"Service is started"}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.265Z - info - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e821","details":"Service is successfully finished"}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.254Z - debug - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e978","details":"About to request the user information","userId": 10}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.254Z - debug - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e978","details":"About to request user orders list","userId": 10}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.257Z - debug - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e821","details":"About to request the user information","userId": 16}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.257Z - debug - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e978","details":"User information is gathered","user":{"id":10,"name":"Alice"}}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.258Z - debug - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e821","details":"About to request user orders list","userId":16}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.259Z - debug - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e821","details":"User information is retrieved","user": {"id": 16, "name": "Michael"}}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.262Z - debug - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e821","details":"User information is retrieved","user":{"id":16,"orders":[{"id":472,"items":{"id":7,"price":7.12}}]}}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.264Z - warn - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e978","details":"Service finished with error","code":404,"err":"Cannot find user orders list"}
2021-08-09T02:12:51.259Z - error - {"transactionId":"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e978","details":"Cannot find user orders list","code": 404,"err":"Not found"}
```

Mandatory fiels are **Date**, **logLevel**, **transactionId**, **details**. Other fields are optional.

I would like to map the json object in the line to an interface but couldn't create the interface.

Could you please help me on this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: @jcalz, I mean couldn't design the interface.

Comment: What, specifically, have you tried?  If you don't [edit] to provide this information then you're likely to get answers like "here, use `interface X { date: Date, logLevel: string, transactionId: string, details: string }`".  If that actually works for you then I'm very surprised that you'd ask here before consulting [basic TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces).  If that *doesn't* work then some information more specific than "I couldn't do it" would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let me fulfill [jcalz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) prophecy haha
Creating an interface is pretty easy in typescript:

```
export interface Item {
   requiredItem: number,
   optionalItem?: string,
   ...
}
```

The export makes it accessible to all other files outside of it's declaration through an import. Now, if you wanted the "optional" items to always appear that presents a different challenge. In typescript, optional items will not be set on an object unless you declare them. In our older code, we make functions to handle cases like this where we always need the properties defined:

```
createItem(values?: any): Item {
     return {
          ...values,
          optionalItem: values.optionalItem ? values.optionalItem : undefined
     } as Item;
}
```

This has it's own problems, because you technically are applying the property twice to your new model. This system also will throw an error if you are using the "strict" flag in typescript and you pass in properties for your `any` that do not meet the interface's requirements. If that is something you are worried about, you could also create a function that takes each property individually or has a "required" object and a "optionals" object and combines them in the function. Without more context though not much more guidance we can give you.